# Xamarin: Prevent other apps from accessing Easy Table

Tags: database, azure, security, authentication, xamarin

I have a Xamarin app that uses Easy Table and uses "Allow anonymous access", this means anybody can access my Easy Table as long as they have the URL. So to increase the security of my app, I would like to allow only my Xamarin app to access the Easy Table I created.

Can this be done by changing the Easy Table option from "Allow anonymous access" to "Authenticated"? And if this is the case should I create an account in Active Directory/Facebook/Google and have the username/password embedded in my Xamarin app such that it can authenticate first before accessing the Easy Table?

Note, I have my own user authentication based on user email address and password and it is working okay, but this is on an application level authentication only(i.e., if users provides correct email address and password, they are able to order, view history, etc.). This obviously will not prevent other apps in accessing my Easy Tables as this authentication uses the Easy Tables in the first place.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Easy Table wordpress?

Comment: Don't have login credentials embedded in Xamarin. People can easily get the code for your application by reverse engineering it.

Comment: No, I meant the Azure Easy Table, as featured in this blog: https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/